# Android WebView page not available - " com.fidelier.printfromweb "

Tags: php, android, html, webview

I have a basic WebView application that should display `www.mysitename.com`.  Though the website can be accessed through the in-built browser and `WebView`,
The only thing I have a problem when I call link in WebView (when I approach paper flows browser, everything is fine)

```
<a onclick = "" href = "com.fidelier.printfromweb: // $ biguhw $ Print From Web intro $ $$ small $ Print small letter $ intro intro $$ $$ $$ intro cut $" data-role = "button" data-inline = "true"> Test print from web </a>
```

(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fidelier.posprinterdriver)

I have ensured:
1. The uses-permission tag for allowing internet access is a child of the manifest tag.
2. Enabled javascript for the WebView.

Comment: could you redefine your question? What happens if you call a link in WebView? Any link or just one special?

Comment: When calling link <a onclick = "" href = "com.fidelier.printfromweb ... I get an error web page not available,  other links work ok

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution  , the problem is opening
external links

```
 @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url){
                if(url.contains("com.fidelier.printfromweb:")){
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true; //the webview will not load the URL
                } else {
                    return false; //the webview will handle it
                }
            }
```